# Can auto-implemented properties be less efficient (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net

Using Visual Studio 2019 and C# (and something VB.NET).

Auto-implemented properties are great syntactic sugar, which I use regularly. But debug any property call (whether to get or set), and a function call appears to be made. Presumably this means pushing and popping onto and off of the stack, just like any function call.

This got me thinking: Properties hide implementation details from consumers of the class, which  is good object-oriented design. However, are they (slightly) less efficient when used internally in the class because of the function call? Is the compiler clever enough to remove the function call and use the private backing field in RELEASE code?

Anyone know the answer? A web search has not delivered the answer.

```
// Example which hopefully makes the question clear
MyClass myClass;
myClass.IntOne = 7;             // Manual property
int testTwo = myClass.IntTwo;   // Auto-implemented property, though the consumer wouldn't know
myClass.DoSomething1(13);       // Is this more efficient...
myClass.DoSomething2(13);       // ...than this?

public class MyClass
{
    // Manual property (with declared, private backing field)
    private int m_IntOne = 0;
    public int IntOne
    {
        get { return m_IntOne; }
        set { m_IntOne = value; }
    }
    
    // Auto-implemented property (with anonymous, private backing field)
    public int IntTwo { get; set; }
    
    public void DoSomething1(int value)
    {
        int localInt = (m_IntOne + value); // Do something with "localInt"...
    }
    
    public void DoSomething2(int value)
    {
        int localInt = (IntOne + value); // Do something with "localInt"...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://sharplab.io/ gives you very easy access to the assembly of compiled code (choose "JIT Asm" under results). Make the methods do something (like `Console.WriteLine`) and compile to release mode, and you'll see that not only do these approaches produce the same code, it's all inlined as well. Beyond that, do keep in mind that premature optimization is the root of all evil, and also heed the [words of a wise man](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) on when to care (and *not* care) about performance even when there *is* a difference.

Comment: Don't repeat my mistake of benchmarking a debug build with a debugger attached. I recently did that with an algorithm where the hot path includes the constructor of a `struct` with auto-implemented properties. Changing them to fields reduces the runtime by 30%. But keeping the auto-implemented properties and running the same benchmark on a release build reduces the runtime by 80%.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [disassembled IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) (link is to the JIT ASM, but you can swap) code for your example, you can see that DoSomething2 does indeed call `get_IntOne()` which reads the backing field.

I've modified the example a little so it does something and isn't optimised away, and you can still see a slight difference:

```cs
public void DoSomething1(int value)
{
    m_IntOne += value; // Do something with "localInt"...
}

public void DoSomething2(int value)
{
    IntOne += value; // Do something with "localInt"...
}
```

```
MyClass.DoSomething1(Int32)
    L0000: add [ecx+4], edx
    L0003: ret

MyClass.DoSomething2(Int32)
    L0000: add edx, [ecx+4]
    L0003: mov [ecx+4], edx
    L0006: ret
```

Whether or not this is a performance issue in your particular application depends on what that application is. The only way to know would be to measure it.

However, the difference is going to be very small (nanoseconds or less), and there may be JIT or CPU optimisations at runtime that avoid any penalty.

I wouldn't worry about this unless you have extreme performance constraints, in which case, I'd expect profiling of everything to ensure it is optimal and lots of non-idiomatic C#.

However, for your typical LOB application, idomatic and readable code will be far more useful than micro-optimisations. There are loads of [great](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79938/what-optimizations-are-premature) [posts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315520/how-to-deal-with-misconceptions-about-premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all) on [premature optimistation](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Just trying to learn! Say the `set` is non-trivial, but the `get` is trivial, then using `m_IntOne` internally doesn't seem like a premature optimisation nor is it less readable.

Comment: Correct, but if you had an auto property, `get` and `set` _cost_ the same.
Typically, people use methods for expensive operations. For example, `set` wouldn't save to a database, you would use a `Save()` method for such an operation.